# Can connect to local MySql database on remote server through Workbench but not Node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js, ssh

I am trying to connect to a mysql database over a remote connection with Node using the packages 'ssh2' and 'mysql2'. My code for connecting looks like below:

```
ssh.on('ready', () => {
  var db_connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    port: 3306,
    user: 'myDBuser',
    password: 'myDBusersPassword'
  });
  
  db_connection.connect();

// The SSH connection is not the issue, so assume correct configuration and working connection
}).connect(sshConfig);
```

When I use the exact same credentials in MySql workbench, I am able to connect to the remote sql server just fine. However, when running this code, I am met with the following error:

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306

  errno: -61,
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 3306,
  fatal: true
```

Does anyone know why Node would have issues with connecting to the remote SQL server? I assume that it is not even passing my credentials to the server and is outright rejecting the connection from the start.

Comment: "**remote** sql server"? 127.0.0.1 is not remote thats localhost ...

Comment: @derpirscher sorry, I could have worded things better. The SQL server is local. But it  is not on my machine. I am SSH'ing into where the SQL server is local to. That is what I meant by remote.

Comment: So you think, the callback of `ssh.on("ready", () => { ... })` is executed on the remote server? No, that's not the case. How would that even work? You can execute shell commands remotly with `ssh.exec(...)` but the JS code is executed locally.

Comment: You can of course use the `ssh2` package to create a tunnel to your remote server and the `mysql2` package is also capable of using such a tunnel, but you have to do a bit more to achive that ... There are some questions here on SO that deal with this, but I couldn't find a recent one with an accepted answer. So I'm linking this blog https://medium.com/swlh/node-js-how-to-access-mysql-remotely-using-ssh-d45e21221039 (yes I know linking external resources is discouraged)

Comment: @derpirscher funny enough, I referred to that article for my solution before even seeing it posted here. Thanks for the info.